# Cómo mostrar un modal bootstrap a partir de una petición ajax swal?

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap

amigos tengo un swal en un codigo ajax

```
            swal({
               
                title: "informacion",

                text: "¿Desea rechazar la solicitud de la cita de : "+login+" ?",

                icon: "info",

                 content: {

                    element: "input",

                    attributes: {

                      placeholder: "Ingrese el motivo del Rechazo",

                      type: "text",

                    },
                },



                buttons: {cancel: true, confirm: true,    cancel: {text: "Cancelar",visible: true}},

            })
```

ahora bien ... es posible que al darle click al boton **cofirm true** y me traiga mas bien una modal de boostrap ya que ese boton confirm true es propio de la modal de js ?

el html de boostrap lo tengo aqui

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_rechazo_citass">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg ">
          <div class="modal-content" >
         <Modal Header>
            <div class="modal-header bg-purple modal-header-padding">
                <center>
                <h5 id="titulo_modal_rechazo_" class="modal-title"> Motivo del rechazo de la cita</h5>
                </center>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; </button>
            </div>
          <!-- Modal body ->
              <div id="toolbar_motivo_del_rechazo" >
                
            </div>
          <label>Motivo del Rechazo de Solicitud</label>
          <input type="text" id="MOTIVO" class="form-control" placeholder="Indique el 
      motivo...">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

de que manera podria hacerlo ? gracias de antemano

Comment: Qué es un "swal"? Te refieres a la librería SweetAlert? Si es así, agrega su etiqueta o especifica de qué se trata. Revisa [example]

Comment: del alert el codigo funciona bien

Comment: Tus comentarios en el código del bootstrap estan mal: Este `<Modal Header>` deberia ser `<!-- Modal Header -->`  y este otro: `<!-- Modal body ->` deberia ser `<!-- Modal body -->` .  Sino se pierde lo que viene a continuacion en el body.  Dudo que eso responda a tu pregunta, pero esta mal puesto aqui al menos.